# Need to rewrite query to select multiple records in secondary table

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
            p.id,
            p.name,
            tc.comment
        FROM people AS p
        LEFT JOIN comments AS tc ON (tc.pID = p.id)
        WHERE p.projID = $project_id
        GROUP BY p.id
```

When it was written originally there used to be a single comment per person, but later it was changed to allow multiple comment from the same person. However, this query only picks the first comment that matches a particular person. I wonder if there's a way to rewrite it in such way that it will pick all comments associated with each person or do I need to separate the comments into it's own query to run within each person's row? That seem quite inefficient though.

Comment: The query above should return all comments. You have no `group by` clause in it.

Comment: Sorry, I actually had a group by, I forgot to type it here. I've fixed it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) aggregate function, that will return all comments combined in a single column:

```
SELECT
  p.id,
  p.name,
  GROUP_CONCAT(tc.comment) AS comments
FROM
  people AS p LEFT JOIN comments AS tc
  ON tc.pID = p.id
WHERE
  p.projID = $project_id
GROUP BY
  p.id,
  p.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the GROUP BY and it will return all of the comments.

```
SELECT
            p.id,
            p.name,
            tc.comment
        FROM people AS p
        LEFT JOIN comments AS tc ON (tc.pID = p.id)
        WHERE p.projID = $project_id
```

Comment: Yes, it does return all comments but it creates a new row for the same participants with each comment instead of having all comments with a single participant row.